# Substitute the pattern of Nth word of a sentence in R

Tags: r, regex

Suppose I have my sentence `txt2 <- "useRs may fly into JFK or laGuardia"`

I could capitalize the first and last letters of the given sentence, and for first word as:

```
sub("(\\w)(\\w*)(\\w)", "\\U\\1\\E\\2\\U\\3", txt2, perl=TRUE)
```

and the last word as:

```
sub("(\\w)(\\w*)(\\w)+$", "\\U\\1\\E\\2\\U\\3", txt2, perl=TRUE)
```

What would be the trick to capitalize the third word as `FlY` using the similar concept in R?

Comment: `sub("(\\w+\\W+\\w+\\W+)(\\w)(\\w*)(\\w)", "\\1\\U\\2\\E\\3\\U\\4", txt2, perl=TRUE)` or `sub("((?:\\w+\\W+){2})(\\w)(\\w*)(\\w)", "\\1\\U\\2\\E\\3\\U\\4", txt2, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks, how would you automate this for `n`th word? say for fly here is `n =3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
txt2 <- "useRs may fly into JFK or laGuardia"
id <- 3
sub(paste0("((?:\\w+\\W+){", id-1, "})(\\w)(\\w*)(\\w)"), "\\1\\U\\2\\E\\3\\U\\4", txt2, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] "useRs may FlY into JFK or laGuardia"
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/SGa4W7). Also, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QYBsEi/1).

Note that `sub` replaces the first match only. The `((?:\w+\W+){2})(\w)(\w*)(\w)`pattern matches

- `((?:\w+\W+){2})` - Group 1: two occurrences of 1+ word chars followed with 1+ non-word chars
  -`(\w)` - Group 2: start word char of a word to be processed
- `(\w*)` - Group 3: the middle of the word to be processed
- `(\w)` - Group 4: last word char of a word to be processed.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach which I, myself, consider not as half robust as @Wiktor's answer:

```r
txt2 <- "useRs may fly into JFK or laGuardia"
n <- 4

gsub(paste0('^(\\s*(?:\\S+\\s+){',n-1,'})\\S+'),
     paste0("\\1",gsub("(\\w)(\\w*)(\\w)", "\\U\\1\\E\\2\\U\\3", 
                       unlist(strsplit(txt2, split=" "))[n], 
                       perl = TRUE)),
    txt2)

 # [1] "useRs may fly IntO JFK or laGuardia"
```

This **replaces** the n<sup>th</sup> word with its capitalized instance (first and last letter) while Wiktor's answer **directly** does the job.